# Using Split() as NewLine Delimiter VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

**INTRODUCTION**

I'm trying to delete a line, and if that value from this line is found in the array.

The values are being entered into a TextBox on a Userform with each value separated by the `NewLine` character.

I think I've managed to pinpoint that the logic is faulty in the `Split()` function. From the research online, I've seen people using...

```
Split(text, Chr(10))
Split(text, Chr(16))
Split(text, vbLf)
```

None of these values (`Chr(10)`,`Chr(16)`,`vbLf`) seem to be working as intended... What seems to be happening is that it will find the `NewLine` character but it's not removing it from the string and keeping the value when placed into the array.

**CODE**

Filling in the data...

```
data() = Split(frmDeleteLines.textData, Chr(10))
''''' Also tested Chr(16) and vbLf
```

Deleting the lines...

```
Private Sub DeleteLines(textArr() As String, column As Long)

   Dim LR As Long

   LR = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

   With ActiveSheet
      For i = LR To 3 Step -1
         If Not (SearchArray(.Cells(i, column), textArr())) Then '<--- Call search array
            .Cells(i, column).EntireRow.Delete 'Delete row if found
         End If
      Next i
   End With

End Sub
```

Searching the array with the compared value...

```
Private Function SearchArray(searchValue As String, textArr() As String) As Boolean

   SearchArray = False

   For i = LBound(textArr()) To UBound(textArr())
      Debug.Print "Comparing: "
      Debug.Print "   ARR: " & textArr(i)
      Debug.Print "   VAL: " & searchValue
      If (searchValue = textArr(i)) Then
         SearchArray = True
         Debug.Print "       DONT DELETE!!!!!"
         Exit For
      End If
   Next i

End Function
```

The `Debug.Print` were for debugging purposes and that's what made me believe the `Split()` function wasn't doing as intended... To my understand the delimiter in the `Split()` function will not be included in the array it's being placed in. Maybe there's something more to it for the `NewLine` value?

**INPUT**

```
123456
789456
456123
456789
```

**COMPARED VALUES**

```
 |_____A____|_____B____|_____C____|
1|  123456  |   BLAH   |   BLAH   |
2|  487964  |   BLAH   |   BLAH   |
3|  456123  |   BLAH   |   BLAH   |
4|  753496  |   BLAH   |   BLAH   |
```

**FINAL RESULT**

```
 |_____A____|_____B____|_____C____|
1|  123456  |   BLAH   |   BLAH   |
2|          |          |          |
3|          |          |          |
4|          |          |          |
```

In theory it should be keeping rows `1` and `3` but it's deleting all of them...

When I viewed the immediate window, I noticed that the values being output were as follows...

```
Comparing: 
   ARR: 123456
   VAL: 123456
Comparing: 
   ARR: 789456

   VAL: 123456
Comparing: 
   ARR: 456123

   VAL: 123456
Comparing: 
   ARR: 456789
   VAL: 123456
```

**QUESTION AT HAND**

Is it my logic that is incorrect? Or is there something funky going on with the `Split()` function in conjunction with the `NewLine` value?

Comment: `VBCRLF` or `chr(13)`

Comment: If the values have been entered into the TextBox with a `vbNewLine` separator, use `Split(text, vbNewLine)`.

Comment: @YowE3K will this work for copy pasting from a notepad as well? What if I copy the text directly from another spreadsheet and paste it directly in there too?

Comment: @YowE3K Also, that worked perfect actually... maybe a little bit more research on my part and I probably wouldn't have had to waste your time. Could have thought I tried everything at that point! Appreciate your help! Please post an answer here so i can mark as answered

Comment: Notepad probably uses CR/LF as line separators (that's fairly standard for text files on Windows systems) so I would specifically use `vbCrLf` for that, but `vbCrLf` and `vbNewLine` are both `x0D0A` in Windows.

Comment: Tested with copying from Notepad and copying straight from Excel and both work using `vbNewLine`

Comment: It depends on the source of the text and the options. There are two text edit controls in Windows, the standard edit control and the rich edit control (that cam mimic an edit control). Edit controls use CRLF. Rich Edit controls use CR by default but the programmer can say use CRLF. Edit controls ignores CR (it becomes a zero width character) unless it precedes a LF. Coping and pasting from richedit or internet can paste CR that notepad ignores. However VBScript does break lines on CR causing bugs that you can't see, what looks like one line of code to you is two broken lines to VBS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your TextBox has been set up to separate values using `vbNewLine` then use `vbNewLine` as your separator in the `Split` function, i.e. `Split(text, vbNewLine)`.

`vbNewLine` is normally equivalent to `Chr(13) & Chr(10)` (i.e. a CR/LF combination).  This will therefore be the same as `vbCrLf`, so all the following should work:

```
data = Split(frmDeleteLines.textData, vbNewLine)
data = Split(frmDeleteLines.textData, vbCrLf)
data = Split(frmDeleteLines.textData, Chr(13) & Chr(10))
```

Comment: The awesome thing about `vbNewLine`, is that if you run your code on a Mac, it won't break :-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug But who would be silly enough to run their code on a Mac?!?!

Comment: *Raises hand* no idea, but if portability is a concern, it's good to know ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug I knew there was a difference between Mac and Windows, and thought it was `vbNewLine` that was the constant that was os-dependent, so made sure I said "normally equivalent to ..." in the answer.   
 (Sane people "normally" use Windows!)  Out of curiosity, what does a Mac use?  Is it just a LF?  (I'll update the answer to add a note to that effect if you let me know.  Or you can update it if your like.)

Comment: Good question. They*forced me* to make my code work on a Mac, no worries... I can find out for sure tomorrow, ...IIRC it's `vbLf`, but don't quote me on that (MSDN has all the info)

Comment: This solution did not work for me, as my text used `vbLf`. I would prefer the solution presented by @user6576927 and simply add all the possible combinations of line breaks (For Mac and Windows). That way I never have to worry about the OS or the string format.

Answer (score 11):

You can accomplish this in function form:

```
Function splitLineBreaks(ByVal str As String) As String
    str = Replace(str, vbCrLf, vbCr)
    str = Replace(str, vbLf, vbCr)
    splitLineBreaks = Split(str, vbCr)
End Function
```

The history of these constants come from the type writer days;

`vbCr` is *Carriage Return* (would return the head to the start of the typewriter)
`vbLF` is *Line Feed* (would move the page one line up)
and often times these two would be combined because it only made sense, into:
`vbCrLf` is *Carriage Return/Line Feed*

Depending on the software you are using, each one of these might do exactly the same thing, or maybe not. But it's always a good idea to check for all these constants when you are looking for your new lines.

Comment: This is actually very helpful too, thank you for your input

Comment: This is a great solution as you can cater for all possible line breaks in the text.

Comment: Shouldn't the first line be
`Function splitLineBreaks(ByVal str As String) As Variant`
At least for me, it fails to compile if the return value is String instead of Variant.